# My research PI has terminated my post-doc after coming back from sick leave. No prior notice given. Is it right behaviour?

Tags: postdocs, legal-issues

I am coming from another country for a post-doc. It's been 2 months and immediately project plan and work pressure started.

Meanwhile, I fell sick and was on leave for one week. When I returned back, they gave me a termination letter.

Is it the right behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do for you. Some pressure for productivity at work is normal in any job; we have no information to judge whether what you experienced was appropriate. Termination due to an illness is quite unfair, but it's not clear this was the reason. Whether you'd have any legal recourse depends entirely on where you are located, as this determines the laws that govern your employment, and any terms of your employment, but if you want to pursue legal remedies you need a lawyer, not internet Q&A.

Comment: And in addition to what @BryanKrause says - regardless of the legal status, your relationship with your advisor is likely irreparably damaged.

Comment: What exactly is the question: how to get reinstated? How to find another job? We'll probably need more details to tell you anything useful...but as Bryan says, I'm not sure how productive this would be.

Comment: This country you come into, is it US?

Answer (score 5):

You ask whether the way you have been treated is "right". There are several ways this could be interpreted. Is it right morally? Is it right legally? And what would you like to be an outcome?

If you were fired soley because you took sick leave, then yes, this is morally wrong, and i think few would disagree. Personally,  I'd still consider it wrong it there were other factors at play,  such as an underlying ongoing physical or mental health problem,  or an on-going performance issue, but no performance management processes. This might not as widely shared.

Whether it is wrong legally will depend on the local laws where you are. In the US it might even depend on the state. You need to take local legal advice. Talk to your local union,  postdoc association or public employment law help line.  In the UK this would be the ACAS helpline. In the UK law says you can be dismissed for any reason in the first 2 years of employment without recourse unless it can be shown to be because of one of the "protected characteristics", which possibly of relevance here would be race and disability. After 2 years employment the reasons you can be dismissed are limited, and the process for firing someone long and complicated. However, most universities will have policies that go above and beyond the law.

The final question is to ask yourself what you would like to happen now. It is highly unlikely that you will get your job back. Many people just want an acknowledgement that they have been mistreated. If that's what you need,  then please take the first part of this post as that. Legal remedy is generally limited to cash. As employment is a contract, this is generally limited to the losses you have suffered as a result of the employer breaching their side of the contract. In the UK for example this is what you would have been paid in this time before you got your next job, or one year's pay at maximum. Wrongful dismissal proceedings often take years.

Answer (score 0):

> immediately project plan and work pressure started. Meanwhile, I fell sick and was on leave for one week. When I returned back they gave a termination letter.

If I were to put on my labour law hat, in which I have some exposure, should I read in-between the line here, on probative base, seemly, there's an *underlying unsatisfactory performance* concern.
Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying of certain, this is the case. However, it's indicative from the *undertones*.
Kindly reflect objectively.

If you're to take this to school authorities, you might get clarity: however, you'll need all the material facts not emotions. They would not most likely reverse the termination letter though. Well, you might just be lucky!

If you then feel like it, take it up with legally. Possibly, get a lawyer: if you're fortunate, one of those no win, no fees. They are not a guarantee though.

There're lots of intricacies. We're not privy to 'em. Quick ones:

- was there a *performance* discussion between you and your host professor before
  -- getting sick
  -- when you returned before the letter
- who is *they* that gave the letter
  -- host professor
  -- dept/school
  -- HR/students affairs
- what's the termination notice in the letter: one month, 3 mths

> Is it the right behaviour

If this is out of the blues, definitely it's not the right behaviour, neither is it the appropriate process. It gives you *strong* ground for redress: depending on the nuances which cannot be determined through a 'faceless' online Q&A.

If you're wondering if the postdoc can be terminated at will, well, in research parlance, yes it can. Same way non-tenured are at the mercy.
For postdocs, a factor is research advancement of the lab/institute/centre. If funding dries up, tough luck. If you're not contributing, ? is why would/should you 'occupy' space. It's a competitive world out there in research: fundings, grants ...

Nonetheless, your host professor could have assisted with soft landing when you commenced. Even at that, you ought to have been proactive

- engage, engage, engage
- enquire, research, enquire

[Postdoc Termination]
Kindly check on your institution's policies. There might just be a '*glimmer of hope*'

- for [Harvard, see postdoc termination process](https://postdoc.fas.harvard.edu/termination-process)
- [Yale's got similar](https://postdocs.yale.edu/faculty/terminations-resignations)

<sub>This is not a legal opinion/advice as contemplated in law</sub>

Comment: Worry biting that employment law varies greatly depending on the country in question.  I'm presuming the advice here is intended to apply to the US. Even in the US I believe the law varies from state to state